# Is it possible to embed Gmail's attachment onto a webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, html, drive

I know that we can embed links and even the contents of most Google Drive files onto webpages. However, is it possible to embed files that have the same properties (looks and functionalities) as Gmail attachments on webpages?

See the pic below:

[image]

Is it possible to put something like this on a webpage with the same functionality as a Gmail attachment?

Thanks!

Comment: too broad question

Comment: it depends on if you save the item in your google drive and set it to share, not private

Comment: There's no built-in thing from Google that does this, but perhaps it's possible. Could you be more specific about the functionality you'd like to produce?

Comment: Basically the following: (1) Same appearance (2) Downloadable button (3) Mini-preview on hover. If there is pretty much no built-in thing, then I guess hard coding out the result is the only option left.